# Hide meta (url, page title, page number) from printed websites

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a client that wants the printed version of their website to not include the url and other meta data that appears in the margin of the page at the bottom (the margin being the centimeter or so of white space around the outside of the printed page). My research shows that this is a setting that can be toggled in a browser's print settings, usually under "margins". I can't seem to find a way to tell the browser to use different settings for print from its default.

Is there a way (perhaps through css or meta tags) to tell browsers to not use their default print settings but instead hide the meta added to the margins? Or is this beyond the scope of what a website can do? (My first guess is that it is strictly prohibited for security reasons, I wouldn't want websites rewriting my settings).

Comment: No, there is no way for your website to alter that

Comment: that's a setting in the print dialog of the browser - you don't have any influence on that from "outside"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through any code that you may introduce into the page. A user will always have the ability to control such things and that is a good thing. If it were possible to do this, it could open up a security hole that no one would want open.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet worked for me in chrome:

```
@page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```